# Can I still directly modify character files in DDLC Plus?

Tags: doki-doki-literature-club

In the original version of *Doki Doki Literature Club*, at certain points in the story you would need to locate the game's data folder and delete specific game files to progress. In the new version, *Doki Doki Literature Club Plus*, this feature seems to have been replaced by a fake computer that appears when you quit the game.

Is there still a way to directly modify character files in the PC version of DDLC Plus? Or can it only be done through the fake PC?

Comment: I had wondered how they would handle that mechanic.. FWIW it is currently/going to be available on console where direct modification would be almost impossible.

Comment: @Gnemlock Edited my question to clarify I am referring to the PC version of DDLC Plus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. According to [a post on Team Salvano's website](http://teamsalvato.com/blog/about-ddlc-plus-datamining-and-modding/), all file modification in DDLC Plus occurs in-game, regardless of which platform you are playing on.

> It’s no secret by now that in the original DDLC game, I hid some Easter eggs within the game files, which added an exciting new layer for fans to explore and speculate about. This worked great on PC platforms, because it was something that anyone could check out for themselves! That’s the nature of PC operating systems; since DDLC was a PC game, I took the opportunity to make use of some features that are only possible on PC by adding those Easter eggs.
>
> Datamining is a different territory. It often requires a technical skillset and specialized tools. Because of that, **we’ve chosen to not make datamining a “gameplay” element of DDLC Plus (for both PC and console platforms – every version of the game has the same content)**. To clarify: In DDLC Plus, all content is discoverable in-game, and none of it requires the use of external tools or software to discover.

Source: [Team Salvano - About DDLC Plus Datamining and Modding](http://teamsalvato.com/blog/about-ddlc-plus-datamining-and-modding/)